# JavaFX ListView adding item into observable list doesn't reflect change and it's not selectable

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx, listviewitem

I have run into pretty messed up behaviour with my ListView, I have listview created in controller with data attached to it.

```
    @FXML
    private ListView<Weapon> listViewWeapons;
     ...
    private final ObservableList<Loadout> loadoutList;

    public LoadoutViewController() {
        ...
        loadoutList =FXCollections.observableList(CsgoRr.getModel().getLoadoutCache());
        ...
    }

 @Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ...
    listViewLoadouts.setItems(loadoutList);
    ...

}
```

I call method attached to button, which has function of adding new loadout into list

```
@FXML
    private void newLoadoutOnAction() {
        try {

            Loadout loadoutToBeStored = new Loadout(new Long[10], "Loadout" + newDuplicateNameLoadoutIncrement);
            loadoutToBeStored.setId(DbUtil.storeLoadout(loadoutToBeStored));//store and set id.
            CsgoRr.getModel().getLoadoutCache().add(loadoutToBeStored);
            System.out.println("Stored new loadout ");
            listViewLoadouts.getSelectionModel().select(loadoutToBeStored);
            for (Loadout loadout : loadoutList) {
                System.out.println("DEBUG LOADOUT CONTAINER OBSERVABLE:" + loadout);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {//duplicate name
            if (ex.getErrorCode() == 23505) {
                newDuplicateNameLoadoutIncrement++;
                newLoadoutOnAction();
            }
            Logger.getLogger(LoadoutViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

All the data is correctly loaded and stored, I have debugged that part  of course. But even though I call method newLoadoutOnAction and I put data into list which observable list has reference to, change is not seen up until I resize that listView. That's not the only problem, even after I resize listView and I'm able to see item in a list I can't select it I have to call construstor and initializer again to be able to select this item. I have never encountered this  behaviour, how do I fix these problems?

**Problem with refreshing item in the list**: I have tried to remove items and set them again, and some other solutions common to this problem bud nothing worked  even if I put setItems(null) I can't get it to work, items are still there.

**Latest item inserted is not selectable** (through UI) until I call my controller again and recreate everything. I have this item selected with code.

```
 listViewLoadouts.getSelectionModel().select(loadoutToBeStored);
```

**This actually selected needed item** bud I don't see any feedback in the UI and I can't select it with my mouse. Even if I remove this line I still can't select it with a mouse till I call my view again (constructor and initializer).

I know this is a bit more complex problem so I decided to show you what's happening with a gif.

[image]

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc for [FXCollections.observableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-) states:

> Note that mutation operations made directly to the underlying list are not reported to observers of any ObservableList that wraps it.

For this reason `loadoutList` is not connected to the list in `CsgoRr.getModel().getLoadoutCache()` after creation. This means that when `newLoadoutOnAction()` calls:

```
CsgoRr.getModel().getLoadoutCache().add(loadoutToBeStored);
```

it is not picked up by `loadoutList`, or the ListView watching it. If you change `CsgoRr.getModel().getLoadoutCache()` to use an ObservableList, and assign that directly to `loadoutList` your function should work as desired.

The other option would be to add your `loadoutToBeStored` to `loadoutList` instead, but then you would need to also synchronise with the List in `CsgoRr.getModel()`

Comment: Thanks @Geoff  i took easy solution of just directly connecting my cache that i made observable, the thing is im still wondering why it works the way it works , i have read documentation before i implemented this bud when i was printing contents everything worked(as it should since its reference) bud hey i didnt checked if view is doing  what is supposed to , data were correct bud as i discovered view wasnt :).