# JavaFX listview duplication of rendered items when added to observableList

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx, observablelist

I have a ListView with observableList attached to it,

```
@FXML
private ListView<Weapon> listViewWeapons;

  .... 
  //initialize
  listViewWeapons.setCellFactory(lv -> new CustomWeaponDetailListCell<>());
  listViewWeapons.setItems(CsgoRr.getModel().getWeaponCache());
```

Custom cell:

```
public class CustomWeaponDetailListCell<T extends Weapon> extends ListCell<T> {

    private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            sb.append(item.getName()).append("    Detail:")
                    .append((String) CsgoRr.objectToJsonString(item.getRecoilPattern()));

            setText(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Function for creating new Weapon and adding it to a database and a list:

```
private static int newWeaponNameIncrement = 1;

@FXML
private void newWeaponOnAction() {
    try {
        System.out.println("DEBUG WEAPON NAME TRYING TO BE CREATED IS :" + "newWeapon" + newWeaponNameIncrement);
        Weapon newWeapon = Weapon.createWeapon("newWeapon" + newWeaponNameIncrement,
                new RecoilPattern());
        newWeapon.setId(DbUtil.storeWeapon(newWeapon));

        CsgoRr.getModel().getWeaponCache().add(newWeapon);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        if (ex.getErrorCode() == 23505) {//duplicate name
            System.out.println("DEBUG :Duplicate name on add new weapon");
            newWeaponNameIncrement++;
            newWeaponOnAction();
        }

        Logger.getLogger(WeaponViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WeaponViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, data is added to a database, but the problem once again is with how I see listView behave.The problem is demonstrated [here in a GIF](https://i.imgur.com/6DFtViw.gifv) (GIF got a bit too big, you have to click link, can't embed it here).

As you can see from image, the problem is that it duplicates items in a list at least visually, so change is refreshed but not in a proper way. Once I change view to something else and then go back, which calls constructor and initialize method, everything looks as it should. Anyone knows what the problem is with this?

Weird part is I have similar code in other controller which points to my previous SO question which I fixed no problem and works flawlessly, but when I do this almost same way I have different results here. [JavaFX ListView adding item into observable list doesn't reflect change and it's not selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196491/javafx-listview-adding-item-into-observable-list-doesnt-reflect-change-and-its-n) 
It's a different problem since before I didn't had any update feedback now I have feedback but not the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reuse the same `StringBuilder` every time the item is swapped without clearing it. This means the resulting `String` will be the concatenation of all values for items that were stored in the `Cell`.

You need to use different `StringBuilder`s every time or clear the `StringBuilder`:

```
public class CustomWeaponDetailListCell<T extends Weapon> extends ListCell<T> {

    private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            sb.append(item.getName()).append("    Detail:")
                    .append((String) CsgoRr.objectToJsonString(item.getRecoilPattern()));

            setText(sb.toString());

            // clear StringBuilder content
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my god i feel so dumb looking everywhere beside here :D , thank you for noticing it , totally forgot to clear it.